# Calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty}(x + \ln(\frac{\pi}2 - \arctan(x))$ using L'hopital's rule

Tags: derivatives

I'm new to L'hopital's rule. I know i need to convert it to $\frac{\infty}\infty$ or $\frac{0}0$. But I have no idea how to convert the following equation. Thanks in advance for your help!

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(x + \ln(\frac{\pi}2 - \arctan(x))$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
Consider $x+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x)\right)=\\
-\ln(e^{-x})+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x)\right)=\\
=\ln\left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x)}{e^{-x}}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

You may also proceed as follows using

- $\operatorname{arccot}x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x$
- $x = \cot u$ while considering the limit for $u \to 0^+$
- $\sin u \ln u = \frac{\sin u}{u}\cdot \underbrace{u \ln u}_{=\frac{\ln u}{\frac{1}{u}}\stackrel{L'Hosp.}{\sim}-u}  \stackrel{u \to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} 0$

\begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{x\to \infty}(x + \ln(\frac{\pi}2 - \arctan(x))
& \stackrel{x=\cot u}{=} & \cot u + \ln u \\
& = & \frac{\color{blue}{\overbrace{\cos u + \sin u \ln u}^{\stackrel{u \to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}1}}}{\sin u}\\
& \stackrel{u \to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} & +\infty
\end{eqnarray*}